# Check Multiple Columns in R

Tags: r

I have a DF and would like to query multiple columns at the same time in an Auxiliary Table. DF Example

```
KEY <- c(123,456,789,111,222,333)
DAY_1 <- c('RICE','','RICE','','RICE','')
DAY_2 <- c('BEAN','','BEAN','','','BEAN')
DAY_3 <- c('POTATO','','POTATO','','POTATO','POTATO')
DAY_4 <- c('LETTUCE','LETTUCE','','LETTUCE','','LETTUCE')
DAY_5 <- c('STEAK','','STEAK','','STEAK','STEAK')
DF <- data.frame(KEY,DAY_1,DAY_2,DAY_3,DAY_4,DAY_5)
```

My Auxiliary Table

```
AUX <- c('RICE','BEAN')
TABLE_AUX <- data.frame(AUX)
```

Therefore, I would like to consult the 5 columns at the same time (DAY_1 to DAY_5) to check if the key consumed any food from the Auxiliary Table (rice **OR** beans).

As a result, I would like to see the following output:

```
KEY <- c(123,456,789,111,222,333)
DAY_1 <- c('RICE','','RICE','','RICE','')
DAY_2 <- c('BEAN','','BEAN','','','BEAN')
DAY_3 <- c('POTATO','','POTATO','','POTATO','POTATO')
DAY_4 <- c('LETTUCE','LETTUCE','','LETTUCE','','LETTUCE')
DAY_5 <- c('STEAK','','STEAK','','STEAK','STEAK')
TEST <- c('YES','NO','YES','NO','YES','YES') 
DF <- data.frame(KEY,DAY_1,DAY_2,DAY_3,DAY_4,DAY_5,TEST)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options to get the output.  Either we loop over the rows, with `apply` and `MARGIN = 1`, check whether there are `any` elements of 'AUX' `%in%` the row, change the logical vector to "YES/NO" by changing to numeric index

```
nm1 <- grep("^DAY_\\d+$", names(DF), value = TRUE)
DF$TEST <- apply(DF[nm1], 1, function(x) c("NO", "YES")[any(x %in% AUX) + 1])
DF$TEST
#[1] "YES" "NO"  "YES" "NO"  "YES" "YES"
```

---

Or with `lapply` and `Reduce`

```
c("NO", "YES")[Reduce(`|`, lapply(DF[nm1], `%in%`, AUX)) + 1]
```

Comment: I saw that your suggestion checks all lines of the file, but I can't do that, I have to limit only to these columns (DAY_1 to DAY_5). What is your suggestion to check only these columns?

Comment: @BrunoAvila. you can subset the columnss.  UPdated the post with `grep`

Comment: @akun, In your example the grep function is for columns with the same name ("DAY"). What is your code suggestion for columns with different names? The work I am developing the columns has different names.

Comment: @BrunoAvila. You can use numeric indexing i.e. `DF[-1]` selects all the columnss except first one. or `DF[2:6]`.  If it is to select only characcter columns `nm1 <- sapply(DF, is.character)` or `factor` `nm1 <- sapply(FD, is.factor)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I did not understand your explanation. If my DAY_2 column called LIGHT, how would you show the new code?

Comment: @BrunoAvila. I meant that if you have no patterns either do the indexing approach i.e. `nm1 <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` and then use `DF[nm1]` or specify the column names as such `nm1 <- names(DF)[2:6]; DF[nm1]`